# How to refactor the boolean logic of this F# function?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I have a list of path I want to filter out. I want to keep only paths matching a specific pattern and remove all paths matching another specific pattern.

To achieve this I pattern matched on each pattern. Here is the code:

```
let stringToSpan (s: string) =
    System.ReadOnlySpan<char>(s.ToCharArray())

let matchWildcard pattern text =
    System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemName.MatchesSimpleExpression(stringToSpan pattern, stringToSpan text)

let filterByPattern (includePattern: string Option) (excludePattern: string Option) (paths: string seq) :string seq =
    paths
    |> Seq.filter
        (fun path ->
            let shouldKeep =
                match includePattern with
                | Some pattern -> matchWildcard pattern path
                | None -> true

            if not shouldKeep then
                false
            else
                match excludePattern with
                | Some pattern -> matchWildcard pattern path |> not
                | None -> true)
```

You can try this snippet with:

```
seq {"test"; "foo/bar"; "foo/toto"}
|> filterByPattern (Some "foo/*") (Some "*toto*")
|> printfn "%A"

// output: foo/bar
```

If it matters, this snippet is used inside a dotnet tool to clone multiple git repositories. You can find this tool on [GitHub](https://github.com/aloisdg/Kamino/blob/main/kamino/Program.fs).

I think that we could improve this snippet a bit. Can we?

Comment: Please follow the guidelines: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Don't call `.ToCharArray()` in your `stringToSpan` function. You're forcing it to allocate a character array on the heap when it's not needed. If there's nothing built into F# to support this, you should call `System.MemoryExtensions.AsSpan(s)` in this function instead.

Answer (score 3):

This could be simplified by using straightforward composition:

```fs
let matches (x: string) (y: string) =
  System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemName.MatchesSimpleExpression
    ( System.MemoryExtensions.AsSpan x
    , System.MemoryExtensions.AsSpan y
    )

seq {"test"; "foo/bar"; "foo/toto"}
|> Seq.filter (matches "foo/*")
|> Seq.filter (matches "*toto*" >> not)
|> printfn "%A"
```

And that's it! Just filter it twice.

This way you don't need to figure out what each of the arguments to `filterByPattern` mean. If you really want to make a function out of it:

```fs
let includeThenExclude include' exclude =
  Seq.filter (matches include') >> Seq.filter (matches exclude >> not)
```

If you only sometimes need to include or exclude, instead of `Option`s:

```fs
let including x = matches x |> Seq.filter
let excluding x = matches x >> not |> Seq.filter

let includingFoo =
    seq {"test"; "foo/bar"; "foo/toto"}
    |> including "foo/*"

let includingFooExcludingToto =
    seq {"test"; "foo/bar"; "foo/toto"}
    |> including "foo/*"
    |> excluding "*toto*"
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets focus on `filterByPattern`.

A Predicate is a function returning a boolean (`'T -> bool`). Since the predicate host most of the logic, lets start by spliting the Predicate from the filter to work on it.

```
let patternPredicate (includePattern: string Option) (excludePattern: string Option) (path: string) :bool =
    let shouldKeep =
        match includePattern with
        | Some pattern -> matchWildcard pattern path
        | None -> true

    if not shouldKeep then
        false
    else
        match excludePattern with
        | Some pattern -> matchWildcard pattern path |> not
        | None -> true

let filterByPattern (includePattern: string Option) (excludePattern: string Option) (paths: string seq) :string seq =
    Seq.filter (patternPredicate includePattern excludePattern) paths
```

Alright now we will stop modifying filterByPattern and focus on patternPredicate. Since we are only dealing with boolean maybe there is a refactoring to do here. Lets switch from pattern matching to basic boolean logic.

```
let patternPredicate (includePattern: string Option) (excludePattern: string Option) (path: string) :bool =
    let shouldKeep = includePattern.IsNone || (includePattern.IsSome && matchWildcard includePattern.Value path)
    if not shouldKeep then
        false
    else
        excludePattern.IsNone || (excludePattern.IsSome && (not (matchWildcard excludePattern.Value path))))
```

`shouldKeep` can be seen as `(not a) or (a and b)` where *a* is the option state and *b* the result of the matching.

Since we don't have to check twice the value of a, `(not a) or (a and b)` can be simplify to `(not a) or b`. If you want to verify this logic, you can use a Truth Table or rely on a tool like [decode.fr's Boolean Expressions Calculator](https://www.dcode.fr/boolean-expressions-calculator)

[image: docde output]

Lets apply this to our function!

```
let patternPredicate (includePattern: string Option) (excludePattern: string Option) (path: string) :bool =
    let shouldKeep = includePattern.IsNone || (matchWildcard includePattern.Value path)
    if not shouldKeep then
        false
    else
        excludePattern.IsNone || (not (matchWildcard excludePattern.Value path))
```

Thats better! Now lets get rid of this `if/else` clause and some parenthesis also.

```
let patternPredicate (includePattern: string Option) (excludePattern: string Option) (path: string) :bool =
    (includePattern.IsNone || matchWildcard includePattern.Value path) &&
    (excludePattern.IsNone || not (matchWildcard excludePattern.Value path))
```

So the complete snippet is now:

```
let stringToSpan (s: string) =
    System.ReadOnlySpan<char>(s.ToCharArray())

let matchWildcard pattern text =
    System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemName.MatchesSimpleExpression(stringToSpan pattern, stringToSpan text)

let patternPredicate (includePattern: string Option) (excludePattern: string Option) path =
    (includePattern.IsNone || matchWildcard includePattern.Value path) &&
    (excludePattern.IsNone || not (matchWildcard excludePattern.Value path))  

let filterByPattern (includePattern: string Option) (excludePattern: string Option) (paths: string seq) :string seq =
    Seq.filter (patternPredicate includePattern excludePattern) paths

seq {"test"; "foo/bar"; "foo/toto"}
|> filterByPattern (Some "foo/*") (Some "*toto*")
|> printfn "%A"

// output: foo/bar
```

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid using Option `.IsNone` and `.Value`, mainly because `.Value` will throw an exception if you made a mistake and called it at the wrong time. Almost all F# code will avoid that property and use pattern matching instead or some other function.

Here's another way to write the `patternPredicate` function, which I renamed to `includePath` do describe what it actually does:

```
let includePath (includePattern: string option) (excludePattern: string option) path =
    let isIncluded =
        match includePattern with
        | Some includePattern -> matchWildcard includePattern path
        | None -> true
    let isExcluded =
        lazy
            match excludePattern with
            | Some excludePattern -> matchWildcard excludePattern path
            | None -> false
    isIncluded && not isExcluded.Value
```

My approach here was to first build up the values `isIncluded` and `isExcluded` so that we can write `isIncluded && not isExcluded.Value`. This breaks the problem down into understandable and explicit parts.

Note the use of a lazy value for `isExcluded`. This means that it won't be evaluated unless `isIncluded` is true, so we don't need to call `matchWildcard` unnecessarily.

Comment: I really like the use of `lazy` here.